# Optimizer for Convolutional neural network

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, computer-vision, convolutional-neural-network

What is the best optimizer for Convolutional neural network (CNN)?

Can I use RMSProp for CNN or only for RNN?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same optimizers you are familiar with for CNNs.

I don't think that there is a **best** optimizer for CNNs. The most popular in my opinion is [Adam](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6980). However some people like to use a plain SGD optimizer with custom parameters.

An excellent article explaining the differences between most popular gradient descent based optimizers can be found [here](http://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/).

Comment: I get better accuracy with default valued SGD than ADAM. I read somewhere that that tends to be the case with CNN's. I'm actually looking for a more definitive answer that does recommend and explain why one is better than the other, as I don't seem to be the only one noticing this when optimizing a CNN. https://towardsdatascience.com/the-3-best-optimization-methods-in-neural-networks-40879c887873

Comment: Here is a link to a white paper on why SGD tends to generalize better than ADAM even though the latter tends to converge faster: https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2020/file/f3f27a324736617f20abbf2ffd806f6d-Paper.pdf